# Multiple rooms authorisation with Spring WebSocket and security

Tags: spring-security, spring-websocket

I'm making multi rooms chat with user authorization: users can have access only to some assigned rooms.

For every room I creating a topic with unique room id

How can I check permissions during the opening socket for reading?

On the server-side, for new inbound connection, I want to get room id from topic URL and check user access permissions for the room. But I didn't find how I can do it. I don't see the place, there it's possible.

**AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer** -- no way for dynamic check

```
@Configuration
class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

   @Override
   protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry message) {
       message.nullDestMatcher().permitAll()
            .simpDestMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
            .anyMessage().hasRole("USER")
   }
}
```

**WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer** -- can't get current url

```
@Configuration
class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
            StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
            if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
               ...
            }
            return message
        }
    });
}
}
```

I know, how to check access during writing messages, but can't find, how to do it during opening a web socket for reading. What is the standard mechanism for this case?

Dependencies:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-spring-websocket:2.5.0.RC1'
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-messaging"
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config" 
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.1.8.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.1.6.RELEASE"
```

**UPDATE**

I can pass room id from the client as a header, but on the server in **configureClientInboundChannel** I can't be sure, that room id in header same with id in topic URL. I can use some hashes, generated on the server-side, but it looks too complex

```
var socket = new SockJS("${createLink(uri: '/stomp')}");
var client = webstomp.over(socket);

client.connect({room-id:"0"}, function() {
   client.subscribe("/topic/room/1", function(message) {
       console.log("/topic/room/1");
   }, {roomId:"1"});

client.subscribe("/topic/room/2", function(message) {
       console.log("/topic/room/2");
   }, {roomId:"2"});                
});
```

Answer (score 1):

During debugging, I have checked headers of command with type StompCommand.CONNECT.

For StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE command current topic URL presented in **simpDestination** header

Final solution is:

```
@Configuration
class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
            StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
            if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
               def currentAuthentication = accessor.getHeader('simpUser') // from spring security 
               String destinationUrl = (String )accessor.getHeader('simpDestination')
               // do check, and throw AuthenticationException   
            }
            return message
        }
    });
}
}
```